# Worst case running time in advance recurrence relation

Tags: graph-theory, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, computational-complexity, branching-rules

I am studying a graph algorithm research article where the worst case running time for a branching rule is expressed as,
$$T\left(n\right)\:=\:T\left(n-2\right)\:+\:T\left(n-3\right)$$
$$=\:O\left(1.325^n\right)$$
How to calculate this type of recurrence relation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The general approach is lined out here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3563106/746312

Answer (score 0):

Following the notation of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3563106/746312), $T(n)=x_n$ can be represented as

$$T(n) = \sum_{j=1}^3 \beta_j\lambda_j^{n-1}$$

where the $\beta_j$ depend on the initial values (which are unknown), and the $\lambda_j$ are solutions of the characteristic polynomial of the linear recurrence. Namely, in your case they satisfy:

$$\lambda^3 = 0\cdot\lambda^2+1\cdot\lambda^1+1\cdot\lambda^0 = \lambda+1\tag 1$$

This means the magnitude of $T(n)$ is dominated by (the absolute value of) the largest solution of (1), which is

$$\lambda_1\approx1.324717957244746$$

so that

$$T(n) \in {\cal O}(1.324718^n)$$

The other two solutions are complex with absolut value smaller than $\lambda_1$:

$$\lambda_{2,3}\approx-0.66236 \pm 0.56228 i,\qquad|\lambda_{2,3}|\approx 0.868838$$

So not only is $\lambda_1$ the dominating eigenvalue, it's also the case that the contributions of the other eigenvalues will be arbitrarily small as $n$ grows.

Comment: Can you suggest me any reference text so that I can learn more about this technique?

Comment: @Sakib: Sorry, no. I am not a pro and cannot provide you with any references.  The idea is to write one step of the iteration as matrix multiplication.  The $n$-th step is them multiplying that matrix $n$ times.  Then use linear algebra (properties of eigenvelues and -vectors) to express this. What might be easier to follow than my link is Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers.  This is just degree 2, not degree 3 like with your question. I didn't find a good derivation of Binet's formula that can easily be neneralized, though.